# Is there a list of STL container methods that may throw an exception anywhere?

Tags: c++, stl

I know the STL will throw on a memory allocation error or if the contained type throws in its constructor / assignment operator.

Otherwise, apparently 'a few' STL methods can throw other exceptions. The example everyone seems to mention is vector::at(), but I can't find a list of the others anywhere.

Does anyone know of such a list?

Comment: I don't know of one. Given that (almost) no two people agree on the boundary between "STL" and "non-STL" parts of the C++ standard library, a simple majority of C++ programmers would probably consider any such list "wrong" in at least some respect.

Comment: @Jerry: the title specifically limits it to STL containers, which has a pretty clear scope (even considering common/tr1 extensions).

Comment: There's also the problem that any user-declared copy ctor, copy op=, move ctor, and move op= can throw anything...

Comment: @Tony: not really. Just for example, is `std::string` an STL container or not? `string` predates the other containers being added to the standard, but now supports `begin()`, `end()`, iterators, etc. so it can be used similarly to those that were originally designed as "containers".

Comment: @Jerry: I would not consider it a STL container, because they've got a much cleaner interface :)

Comment: @Matthieu: which demonstrates the problem quite nicely -- because I certainly know of people who *do* consider it an STL container.

Comment: @Jerry: that was the intent of my remark :) For me there are 4 parts to the standard library, the Cish part, the IO stream part, the String part and the STL part. But I freely admit it's really blurry.

Comment: @Matthieu: I'm not quite sure where `valarray` fits in those categories, but perhaps you're just ignoring it. I guess it would be hard to blame you for that -- everybody else certainly does. :-)

Comment: @Jerry: are you thinking of the string class that e.g. libg++ provided?  If so, it is completely unrelated to the STL's string in everything but problem domain (e.g. not templated; member functions include contains, matches, freq, before, operator(pos,len) for substrings, through, from, after, del, gsub, common_suffix, replicate, reverse, upcase, etc..).  If that was the pre-STL string you're thinking of, then std::string wasn't just an STL-algo compatible extension of it but a complete redesign.  Anyway, Matthieu's proven your point, albeit with an incredible justification ;-P.

Comment: @Tony: I'm thinking of what the committee was designing, and then re-designed to fit more closely with the new "STL" containers, after they were accepted into the standard.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Won't be 100% accurate, and is for **C++03**, but a half-hour effort based on grepping through GCC 4.3.4 includes, ignoring tr1 and ext but including iostream.  Crucially, some of these checks might be due to this implementation prefering more defensive coding, and might not be mandated in the Standard and available universally....

- `bitset`

  - `std::overflow_error` - `.to_ulong()` when too many bits to fit in unsigned long
  - `std::out_of_range` - `operator[]()` attempt past end
- `new`

  - `std::bad_alloc`
- `typeinfo`

  - `std::bad_cast` on invalid `dynamic_cast` attempt
- `ios`

  - `std::ios_base::failure` when using exception masks for error reporting
- `string`

  - `out_of_range` - `at`/`append`/`assign`/`insert`/`erase`/`replace`/`copy`/`substr`
  - `length_error`: attempt to exceed `max_size()` during `reserve` or implicit resize (e.g. `assign`/`insert`/`+=` etc.)
- `locale`

  - `std::bad_cast` if locale doesn't contain a facet of type `Facet`
  - `std::runtime_error` in various null-pointer/undefined-facet situations
- `deque`/`vector`

  - `length_error`: attempt `reserve()` or implicitly-grow > `max_size()`
  - `out_of_range`: `at()`
- `map`

  - `std::out_of_range`: `at()`

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have this big, gigantic book titled, **The C++ Standard**, that contains a complete description of all functions in the standard library and what they can/cannot do.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunatly my algorithm for extracting the required information is buggy. That is, I might miss one :-)