# What libraries would be useful for implementing a small language interpreter in C?

Tags: c, interpreter

For my own learning experience, I want to try writing an interpreter for a simple programming language in C – the main thing I think I need is a hash table library, but a general purpose collection of data structures and helper functions would be pretty helpful. What would you guys recommend?

Answer (score 6):

[libbasekit](http://www.dekorte.com/projects/opensource/libbasekit/) - by the author of Io. You can also use libcoroutine.

Comment: It seems like Steve Dekorte has made several libraries that would be really useful for me - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One library I recommend looking into is **libgc**, [a garbage collector for C](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/).

You use it by replacing calls to `malloc`, `realloc`, `strdup`, etc. with their libgc counterparts (e.g. `GC_MALLOC`).  It works by scanning the stack, global variables, and GC-allocated blocks, looking for numbers that might be pointers.  Believe it or not, it actually performs quite well (almost on par with the *very good* [ptmalloc](http://www.malloc.de/en/), which is the default (non-garbage collected) `malloc` implementation in GNU/Linux), and a lot of programs use it (including [Mono](http://www.go-mono.com/) and [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/)).  A disadvantage, though, is it might not play well with other libraries you may want to use, and you may even have to recompile some of them by hand to replace calls to `malloc` with `GC_MALLOC`.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly - and I know some people will hate me for it - but I recommend you use C++.  You don't have to bust a gut to learn it just to be able to start your project.  Just use it like C, but in an hour you can learn how to use std::map<> (an associative container), std::string for easy textual data handling, and std::vector<> for a resizable heap-allocated array.  If you want to spend an extra hour or two, learn to put member functions in classes (don't worry about polymorphism, virtual functions etc. to begin with), and you'll get a more organised program.

Comment: I've used C++ before and it seems like a fairly good fit, but I'm just used to hearing so many bad things about it that I was somewhat hesitant. Now that I think about it, though, most JavaScript implementations are written in C++, so maybe it's not that bad after all :)

Comment: Bad things from people who don't know what they are talking about! C++ is essentially C with additional tools; if you don't use those additional tools, it can be no worse than C.  If you are implementing a programming language then std::stack<> will be useful for many things.

Comment: @Clifford: I disagree. Sure C++ is (almost) a superset of C, C code is very different from C++ code, though. C++ takes a very different route from C to accomplish things. Once you decide to use C++, you should go C++ all the way and not just write C code and borrow a few things from C++. Mixing C and C++ is good way to write crappy code.

Comment: @Fabian: I don't think we do disagree at all.  I was not actually recommending only using the C subset of C++, merely pointing out that it is a bigger tool-set, which cannot be bad except in teh wrong hands.  It is not C++ that is bad, but quite possibly those advising him were simply bad at C++ (or perhaps did not grok OOP).  I do disagree with *"C code is very different from C++ code"* however, I would agree that OO code is different from procedural code however, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @Clifford: I agree, C++ is not bad in itself. I think I misinterpreted (no pun intended) a bit your comment. But it's not only OO that makes C++ code differ from C code. Once you start using stl data structures, you'll have to worry about exception safety. This of course has also its impact (RAII) on the code and also makes C++ code different from C code.

Comment: @Fabian: But STL is part of the C++ library, not the C++ language; they are distinct.  For example, I use C++ in relatively small embedded systems with real-time constraints and critical reliability requirements. Consequently much of the C++ library is avoided altogether. Not because STL or other parts of the library is unreliable or slow, but because much of it is non-deterministic in its performance due to under-the-hood dynamic memory management.

Comment: @Fabian: The STL generates two main categories of exceptions: out of memory, and basically invalid indices (ignoring locale facets - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273057).  For many purposes, it's not unreasonable to handle the first with a try/catch around `main()`, and the second can be avoided with the same care that is necessary to avoid invalid indexing in equivalent C programs anyway - effectively used as an incomplete assertion mechanism to report some programmer errors.

Comment: @Clifford: I was referring to your comment to use std::stack. Sure, you don't have to use STL to write good C++ code. My point is that the features of C++ work neatly together, especially exception handling and OO (automatic destruction of stack objects). Which, besides templates, are IMO the main features of C++ over C. There is a synergy between these features. When not using one of these features, the other feature doesn't work quite as well as it could.

Comment: @Fabian: your points to Clifford are valid, but please remember I'm suggesting C++ as a high-return-on-minimal-investment way to get container features for what would otherwise be a C program, written by a C programmer without solid existing C++ expertise.  Many C++ features do complement each other, but if you expect someone to do their first project entirely in C++ style then you're unnecessarily making the transition into a hurdle.  It's a good thing that C programmers can edge their way in gently and pick up C++ features as they evolve an understanding of their benefits.

Comment: @Tony: You're right, I was not taking the lack of existing C++ skills into my perspective. Because writing the interpreter is purely for education purposes (no production code quality required), it can be used as an introduction to C++.

Answer (score 0):

You need no more than the standard library for a suitably small language with simple constructs.  The most complex part of an interpreted language is probably [expression evaluation](http://www.arstdesign.com/articles/expression_evaluation.html).  For both that, procedure-calling, and construct-nesting you will need to understand and implement stack data structures.

The code at the link above is C++, but the algorithm is described clearly and you could re-implement it easily in C. There again there are few valid arguments for not using C++ IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Before diving into what libraries to use I suggest you learn about grammars and compiler design. Especially input parsing is for compilers and interpreters similar, that is tokenizing and parsing. The process of tokenizing converts a stream characters (your input) into a stream of tokens. A parser takes this stream of tokens and matches it with your grammar.

You don't mention what language you're writing an interpreter for. But very likely that language contains recursion. In that case you need to use a so-called bottom-up parser which you cannot write by hand but needs to be generated. If you try write such a parser by hand you will end up with a error-prone mess.

If you're developing for a posix platform then you can use lex and yacc. These tools are a bit old but very powerful for building parsers. Lex can generate code that implements the tokenizing process and yacc can generate a bottom-up parser.

My answer probably raises more questions than it answers. That's because the field of compilers/interpreters is quite complex and cannot simply be explained in a short answer. Just get a good book on compiler design.